# Why does the following code produce Object Disposed Exception

Tags: c#, winforms

I am playing around in visual studio and getting to know C# better. I am coming from an intermediate background knowledge of Java.

I have produced a very simple windows form application. The user clicks on a button, the button takes them to another screen, the user types into a textbox and presses a button in which that button will display what the user typed in; in the form. This is the code:

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form


    {
        Form2 userinputForm;
        public Form2 getSetForm2 {
            get { return userinputForm; }
            set { userinputForm = value; }
        }

        Form1 homeFormObj;
        public Form1 getSetForm1 {
            get { return homeFormObj; }
            set { homeFormObj = value; }
        }



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getSetForm2 = new Form2();
            getSetForm1 = this;
            getSetForm2.formOnePublicObj = getSetForm1;
        }

        internal void displayUserInput(string name)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Text = name;

            panel1.Controls.Add(l);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userinputForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 formOneObj;
        public Form1 formOnePublicObj {
            get { return formOneObj; }
            set { formOneObj = value; }
        }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<string> userinputs = new List<string>();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = textBox1.Text;
            formOnePublicObj.displayUserInput(name);

        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs the second time the user presses the button to go to form2. it occurs on the .show() method.

(P.S I coded like this to see how I can pass data from one windows form to another hence the getters and setters on the form objects).

Comment: A better way to pass data between forms is use a 3rd object as a data store then pass that same object to both forms. This is the logic behind coding techniques like [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx), the object that is passed to both forms is the "Model".

Comment: It is buggy, you keep a reference to a dead object.  Use Form2's FormClosed event to know that it is a dead parrot, reset the *userinputForm* back to null.  Or don't allow it to die, use the FormClosing event and call Hide() and e.Cancel = true so it stays around.

Comment: @HansPassant So when a form gets closed (i.e. user presses the X button), that WHOLE form object is destroyed?

Comment: @Tarikh Yes. Read my answer below for further details.

Comment: Yes, not in parts either.  Follows the "natural" way, when the user clicks Close then he invariably means "don't need you anymore, bye".  Overriding the user's intention is a programmer's job.  Maybe you shouldn't, it is not the .NET way in general.  Create an object only when you need it and you don't have to fight the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `userinputform` is never set and so is `null`. As such I don't understand why it works the first time unless this isn't actually your code pasted in.

It's probably because you're closing the second form, which is destroying it therefore you can't show it again. Each time you click the button in form1 create a new form2:

```
        getSetForm2 = new Form2();
        getSetForm1 = this;
        getSetForm2.formOnePublicObj = getSetForm1;
```

Comment: `userinputform` does get initalised at `getsetForm2 = new Form2()` as it initalises it through the getters/setters. At your second point, yeah I was thinking of that. When I do implement that code, the user can spam the button in Form1 which pop ups a lot of Form2. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Not in the code you posted above. userinputform is never set. What do you mean by "spam the button"?

Comment: what i mean is that if they user presses the button on form1 5 times, then how can i prevent form2 from showing multiple times at the same time?